# Intermediate Value theorem for subtracted fucntions

Tags: calculus

If i have 2 functions f and g, both with the domain [a,b] interval. Where both are continuous. Also, f(a)>g(a) and f(b)<g(b), how would i use intermediate value theorem to show there exists a c in [a,b] for the fucntion h(x)=f-g such that f(c)=g(c)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What can you say about $h(a)$ and $h(b)$?

Comment: That h(a)>0 and h(b)<0??

Comment: @john And then what does the intermediate value theorem tell you?

Comment: That if these are satisfies there is a solution?

Comment: im kinda new to IVT sorry

Comment: @john A solution to what?

Comment: to the intitial statement that there exists a c that f(c) = g(c)?

Comment: @john You're skipping a step. Since $h(a)>0$ and $h(b)<0$, what _exactly_ does the IVT say?

Comment: That there exists a c where h(c)=0?

Comment: @john Yes, that's it. Now, remembering the definition of $h$, what does this say about $f(c)$ and $g(c)$?

Comment: that f(c) must equal g(c) for the subtraction of them to equal 0

Comment: thanks for the help